# City is not a valid model for User

Tags: python, django

I have extended my custom user model to include the fields; city and country. Problem is when I do a `GET` request to the appropriate end-point I get the error

```
Field name `city` is not valid for model `User`.
```

This is my code starting with urls.py

```
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
...
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
```

UserViewSet:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    #changed name from UserSerializer to RegisterSerializer
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer
   
    @action(detail=True, methods=['POST'])
    def set_password(self, request, pk=None):
        user = self.get_object()
        serializer = PasswordSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            user.set_password(serializer.validated_data['new_password'])
            user.save()
            return Response({'status': 'password set'})
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors,
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and RegisterSerializer:

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        #removed url from fields
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'city', 'country', 'bio']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True},
        }
        def create(self,validated_data):
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                                            username=validated_data['username'],
                                            first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
                                            last_name=validated_data['last_name'],
                                            email=validated_data['email'])
            user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
            user.save()
            #added fields from profile
            user.profile.city = validated_data['city']
            user.profile.country = validated_data['country']
            user.profile.bio = validated_data['bio']
            return user
```

Comment: When you write `model = User` in your serializer are you sure `User` is imported from the correct place? Also have you set `AUTH_USER_MODEL`?

Comment: it looks like you have "city" on the `user.profile` model? If that's the case you shouldn't include them in the `fields` of the RegisterSerializer.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat User is imported from the correct place

Comment: @Ben maybe a dumb question, but how would I retrieve that information then (ie. what city a user is in if that's contained in user.profile)

Comment: Oh, `city` is from the profile model contrary to what you state in your question (Please see [ask] and how to write a [mre])... If you want your serializer to have a field not in the same model you have to _explicitly declare_ the field, you can use the [source](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) argument so that DRF will know where to get the value from

Comment: Yes, what @AbdulAzizBarkat wrote. You need to declare city, country, bio separately from the model fields.